# Input field values not arithmetically summing up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goodday, please i have a code to calculate the efficiency of a generator. The problem is the input fields all add up until the last variable. If all values were 2+2+3+4 which normally sums up into 11 normally, this program doesn't do that instead it just adds the 4 as in 2+2+3+4 equals 74.

That's the formula for calculating the efficiency of a generator.
[image: That's the formula for calculating the efficiency of a generator.]

```
$('.efmit').on('click', function efficiency() {
 var vI = $('.I').val();
 var vV = $('.V').val();
 var ia = $('.ia').val();
 var If = $('.If').val();
 var Ra = $('.Ra').val();
 var closs = $('.closs').val();

 var vi_combo = vI*vV;
 var ias = (ia*ia)*Ra;
 var iv = If*vV;


var cent = 100;
var result = vi_combo+ias + iv;
var finalR = result + closs;

window.alert(finalR);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery val method like `$('.closs').val()` returns String type variable not Number type.

You can cast type of variable to solve the problem.

```
var closs = Number($('.closs').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your program treated your variable as a `string` 
try converting them to `integer` by parsing them like this `parseInt(yourVariable)`.